# Ocultar fila de una tabla cuando su valor sea 0

Tags: php, mysql, datatables

Saludos desarrolladores...

Vengo a dejar mi aportación, de como ocultar las filas de una tabla (Data Table) con javascript de manera sencilla, espero y les pueda ayudar.

ID de mi tabla es: myTable

```
<script>
        window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  [...document.querySelectorAll("#myTable tbody tr")].forEach(
      row => row.classList.toggle("hide", row.cells[1].textContent.trim() === "0")
  );
});
    </script>
```

Imagen de mi tabla Antes ->
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Imagen de mi tabla Despues ->
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Primero, no pongas imagen de código, pon el código en el tag correspondiente. Segundo, porque no evalúas con un condicional y si es 0 algún dato lo ocultas? o mejor aun solo pintas aquello que sea mayor que 0

Comment: Si se que con una condicional se puede, pero es que soy novato y quisiera que me guiaran mas o menos estructurar esa parte...

Comment: Edita tu pregunta. Pon el código y veré como te ayudo. Pon todo el código del archivo de la imagen que subiste.

Comment: Listo, puse un link donde puedas observar mi código completo

Comment: ¿Por qué no lo haces desde la consulta SQL?

Comment: Si ocultas una fila debes considerar que algunos de sus valores no será 0 y por ende podrías estropear el formato de la salida, deberias hacer esto desde SQL para que el formato de salida sea el correcto.